# How to pass the dimensions of one multidimensional array to another in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

There are two arrays of int arrays (int [][]). The method takes the array A as a parameter and its output should be another array B with the inverted values of sub-arrays of the array A (which is another topic).
I'm trying to declare and initialize the array B, but getting an error "array dimension missing". 
The question: how can I pass the parameters/dimensions of array A to the array B in the initialization?

```
public int[][] reverseSubArrays(int[][]A) {
int[][] B = new int[][];
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all the arrays are of the same size then you can specify both the row and column count i.e.:

```
int[][] b = new int[rowCount][columnCount];
```

or if the array can be jagged then you're after:

```
int[][] b = new int[rowCount][];
```

Comment: where do I get `rowCount` from? Would it be `A.length`?

Comment: @DariaIvanova yes

Comment: and what about `columnCount`?

Comment: for `columCount` you'll have to use the loop though each row and see what are the lengths.

Comment: @DariaIvanova since you're asking for `columnCount` I am assuming you actually have a  _multidimensional_ array as opposed to a jagged array, in which case you can do `A[0].length` to get the `columnCount`. if there is a chance that the arrays can be length `0` then make sure to do necessary checks before accessing the element at the aforementioned index.